# UIImageJPEGRepresentation creates a white bottom bar

Tags: image, jpeg, avcapturesession, uiimagejpegrepresentation

I am using `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` after I capture an image with `AVCaptureSession` and `AVCaptureStillImageOutput`. For some reason when I compress my images with `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` the image has a thin white line at the bottom of the picture. Does anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was actually that I was resizing my image, but in doing so the proportions didn't line up so there is an empty pixel row on the bottom that defaults to white because the file is a jpeg. See the link below

[A thin whiteline is been added when resize the image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081356/)